# mxmlc does not include *.ane files during command line build

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxmlc, ane

Here is the command that I am using to build an android application.

```
mxmlc
+configname=airmobile 
-output Example.swf 
-locale=en_US -source-path+=D:\fb_projects\Example\localeB\{locale} 
-library-path+=D:\fb_projects\Example\libs 
-source-path+=D:\fb_projects\Example\src 
-external-library-path+=D:\fb_projects\Example\extensions\android.ane 
-- D:\fb_projects\Example\src\Example.mxml
```

Update :

Please check the command that i am using now to build/compile my flex android application , I have modified the command as per dump config

```
mxmlc
+configname=airmobile 
-output Example.swf 
-locale=en_Eng 
-source-path+=
    D:\fb_projects\Example\localeB\{locale} 
-source-path+=
    D:\fb_projects\Example\src,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\assets,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\extensions,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\localeB 
–library-path+=
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\authoringsupport.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\charts.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\flash-integration.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\framework.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\osmf.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\rpc.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\spark.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\textLayout.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\mobile\mobilecomponents.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\air\servicemonitor.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\advancedgrids_rb.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\airframework_rb.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\automation_rb.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\charts_rb.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\framework_rb.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\mx_rb.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\osmf_rb.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\rpc_rb.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\spark_rb.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\locale\en_Eng\textLayout_rb.swc,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\libs\ButtonComponent.swc,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\libs\controlAcceptor_swc.swc,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\libs\fileItem_swc.swc,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\libs\GraphAPI_Mobile.swc,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\libs\mcSearchNoResult.swc,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\libs\PureMVC_AS3_2_0_4.swc,
    D:\fb_projects\Example\libs\search_swc.swc,
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\themes\Mobile\mobile.swc
-namespace 
    http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009 C:\AIR21\frameworks\mxml-2009-manifest.xml 
-namespace 
    library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark C:\AIR21\frameworks\spark-manifest.xml 
-external-library-path+=
    C:\AIR21\frameworks\libs\air\airglobal.swc 
-library-path+=
    D:\fb_projects\Example\extensions\android.ane 
-- D:\fb_projects\Example\src\Example.mxml
```

ADT Command :

```
adt 
 -package -target apk 
 -storetype pkcs12 -keystore android.p12 -keypass password 
 Example.apk Example-app.xml Example.swf 
 icons
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Does it not compile or are you getting a runtime null pointer exception because ANE was not included in the build ? Does it compile without ANE? Shouldn't it be someting like " -- D:\fb_projects\Example\src\Example.mxml" at the end ?

Comment: Getting a `ClassNotFoundException` whenever something in the ANE is invoked - _probably_ because it is not being included in the final build (.apk).

Comment: I think , .ane is not get included in the .swf (compiled file).

Answer (score 1):

As per the flex [compiler options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html) you can see that '*external-library-path*' will not link your ANE file. You should use '*library-path*' instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply , @robin , still not worked i have changed what you have suggested. updating the command i am using now. Please guide if doing something wrong